# Runtime Error-2147217904(80040e10)

Tags: sql, vba

I have Transactions table, in the table I have DOT(Date Of Transaction) field. I want to get transactions of a particular month in a particular year, irrespective of day. So tried by this Query.

```
>>>  SQL = "SELECT * FROM Transactions
WHERE DATEPART(MM, (SELECT DOT FROM Transactions))= " & Month(Date) & " 
AND DATEPART(YY, (SELECT DOT FROM Transactions))= " & Year(Date) & ""
```

but I am getting automation error and error showing at  `rs.Open SQL, cnn`.

where rs is recordset object , cnn connection object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perfect query is below:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Transactions t WHERE DATEPART('m', t.[DOT])= MONTH(DATE()) " & _ 
      "AND DATEPART('yyyy', t.[DOT])= YEAR(DATE())"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're involving subqueries when you can access the field from the Transactions table directly.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Transactions t " & _
      "WHERE DATEPART(mm, t.[DOT])=MONTH(getdate())" & _
      " AND DATEPART(yy, t.[DOT])=YEAR(getdate());"
```

Given that MS SQL's T-SQL has its own MONTH, YEAR and getdate(), there is no reason to construct these parameters before sending the SQL statement.

If the above is not working for you, then you will have to provide the database parent that the Transactions table is located in. Something like [MyDB].dbo.[Transactions ]. Try the statement at the server.

Comment: hi Jeeped this getting error number... 2147217904(80040e14)- Automation Error. I forgot to say that I am trying to use this in excel vba...